# Fetch errorundefined swagger/v1/swagger.json .Net Core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

**Fetch error undefined swagger/v1/swagger.json .Net Core 3.1 API**

I have tried almost everything, Can anyone help me to get this fix.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add symbol `/` just before `swagger`:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "IRIEO.API");
});
```

Comment: Have tried but still getting the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Sheriff,it maybe because your project have some internal error which do not work in swagger.If you project is not complex and share a github repo will be helpful.If your project is complex,you need troubleshooting by check the `output` panel in visual studio when your browser display the error.

Comment: There is no error in the project, successfully building and running.

Comment: @Sheriff I agree with @Rena, you, probably, have an issue in a part that you haven't shown. I would suggest to create a fresh, empty WebApi project `dotnet new webapi`, add to that project swagger UI and step by step move your logic into that new project, controlling on each step that swagger UI working.

Comment: @Sheriff,please look at your `output` panel when you run the application to display swagger document.The panel will display detailed error message.

Comment: @IgorGoyda - Cann't create fresh project

Comment: @Rena, nothing getting at output window related to swagger or any error.

Comment: Hi @Sheriff,It's impossible that you do not have error in your project.Be sure choose debug module for your output and enable log in your project.

Comment: Oddly enough this was super helpful for me, i actually had re-used a class name and it was throwing an error internally, even though the code compiled fine, swagger was super unhappy.

Answer (score 1):

when your controller has a problem usually shows that error, check the code of your controller, in my case I forgot to put the [HttpDelete("{id}")] in a method and that's why I gave that error. in the debugging console it should show you the error, just look for it because it is quite text.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a HttpPost then you need to make sure you give it a name.

```
[HttpPost(nameof(UpdateContactDetails))]
```

and not just

```
[HttpPost]
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Output console as suggested by Carlos Javier Bazan.
In my case it was an error in the controller: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - WebsiteR3.Controllers.WHhandlerController.UpdPaymentStatus

Answer (score 1):

Swagger may throw this error when there are more than one endpoints with the same routing URL. Just give a try by resolving the action route URLs across all controllers and make each URL unique.

Answer (score 1):

Check all of the above, because it could be any of these. 
But make sure to also check, that the route is unique. In my case

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class MyApiForFooAbcCalcController : ControllerBase
{
   // ...
}
```

the route "api" was already defined in a 2nd controller class of the project, which caused the conflict. Although the methods in both classes all had different names (and attributes for HttpGet, HttpPost, ...), the conflict was there and caused the runtime error. Note that it compiles without any error.

To resolve, add a more specific route for each class, e.g.:

```
[Route("api/forFooAbcCalc")]
```

and in the other one something like

```
[Route("api/forFooXYZCalc")]
```

which will then compile and run again!

Answer (score 0):

Following the instruction on swagger on microsoft there is a line that says:
navigate to: https://localhost:/swagger/v1/swagger.json

If you have errors they will show up when you do so, and with an indication which error it is

Answer (score 0):

Can have few reasons for the issue

1. Controls/Actions are not derived with correct data annotations
2. Controls may have public methods other than Action methods. Make sure you have only private non action methods.